# Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, sfml

After people told me to shorten the program I did it and here is the shortened version of the program with the same error as stated above.It only appears after a few moments into the program.If i hit continue the program works fine.However see the movement function?It does't work.The sprite refuses to move in any direction.However if i give a very large floating value in the move,then the sprite is displaced from it's position when i start the program and it stays there in that position with no further movement.For example if i write sprite.move(400.f,400.f) the sprite moves from (0,0) to (400,400) and stays there.It doesn't move any more.
    Here's the shortened version of the code:

```
#include"SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include<iostream>
int main()

{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "CHECK",sf::Style::Default);
std::cout << "WORKS";
sf::Texture text;
text.loadFromFile("bahamut.png");
sf::Sprite sprite;
sf::Clock frap;
sprite.setTexture(text);
while (window.isOpen())
{
    float fps = frap.restart().asSeconds();
    sf::Vector2f movements;
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A))
    {
        movements.y = 0;
        movements.x = -1 * fps;
    }
    else
  {if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D))
    {
        movements.y = 0;
        movements.x = 1 * fps;
    }
    else
   {    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S))
    {
        movements.y = 1 * fps;
        movements.x = 0;
    }
       else
     {
      if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W))
      {
        movements.y = -1 * fps;
        movements.x = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        movements.x = 0;
        movements.y = 0;
      }
     }
    }
   } 
    sprite.move(movements);
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();

}
return 0;
}
```

I improved upon the code and it still produces the same results and error.
On using the dissassembler i saw the crash occurs at

00B37AEE  cmp         esi,esp
in window.display().
when i create a function and use it to display the sprite,the movement occurs but witthout the unction nada

Comment: you should firstly initialize your movement to a zero vector,  if you are only going to allow a movement of either < > up or down, you dont need all the if elses you can do this with just if statements since you are overriding every element in movements anyways.  How long are you waiting to see your sprite move?  To notice any significant movement you would have to hold a key down for atleast 3 seconds to see him move 3 pixels based off of your movement speed(Assuming it stores its position with a vector of floats...).  As for the error message, I cant do much without seeing your call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic says your movement is 0/0 if W is *not* pressed. The `else` of the W pressed block overrides all prior settings. And moving the sprite should happen before you `display`.

I cannot see a reason for the null pointer exception, but that is what the debugger is for. Next time this happens, debug.

Oh and it's `int main()`, not `void`. I know the compiler tolerates this error, but it's still an error and undefined behavior.

Comment: wait i remember using void in c++ why cant we use void here? And could you please help me in this debugging part.I found the stack trace which was completely unhelpful.I had no idea what it was about.

Comment: You can use `void main()` if you compiler allows it, it's just wrong and the next compiler or version of your compiler could rightfully do anything he likes with your code if it starts with `void main()`. So don't do it. The debugging part is what happens if you don't press "continue". I cannot really help you with it over the internet, you will have to try and read a good book or tutorial on it.

Comment: Hey I edited the code with the else statements now but it still doesn't work.I'm trying to look up the debugging part.Will it help if I post the stack trace ?Please I know I'm being stupid and stuff but please help me I'm the novice here

Comment: Debugging is a skill. I cannot teach you a skill in 255 characters over the internet. Please go and read a book or watch a youtube tutorial on "How to debug". You are not stupid, we all had to learn this at some point in our careers. But that does not mean we can somehow teach you without you doing the very same thing we did: read up on it.

Comment: oh and on introducing breakpoints it tells me window.display()is the next line to be executed